# How to have one route with multiple schema for different parameters using fastify?

Tags: typescript, docker, routes, jsonschema, fastify

I have the following route in my middleware using fastify:

Route.ts
server.get('/rest/api/cars/:twofourdoors/:autoManual/', { schema: getCarsSchema }, getCars(server));

Basically user have 4 options in this route two or four doors and automatic or manual. I have a single schema in my .schema like:
schema.ts

```
const carSchema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    wheels: { type: 'string' },
    color: { type: 'string' },
    gears: { type: 'string' },
    maxAutoSpeed: { type: 'string' },
    maxManualSpeed: { type: 'string' },
    twoDoorSize: { type: 'string' },
    fourDoorSize: { type: 'string' },
  },
};
    export const getCarsSchema = {
      summary: 'Get cars',
      description: 'Get cars by types',
      query: querySchema,
      response: {
        200: {
          type: 'object',
          properties: {
            totalItems: { type: 'number' },
            pageNumber: { type: 'number' },
            items: { type: 'array', items: carSchema },
          },
        },
        501: logMessageSchema,
      },
    };
```

the carSchema is just a list of all car attributes. What i want is the following:

1. Can i use one schema to return custom attributes per the different options in route?
2. If 1 can't be achieved, can i provide 4 different schemas to the route for each combination of options?

I am not sure how to approach this. thanks!

Comment: I think you might need to provide some more information here. Please provide your full schema including `carSchema`, and provide an example of the payload you want to validate. Currently, I cannot tell exactly what you're asking. Can you expand on " return custom attributes per the different options in route"?

Comment: sorry was away but i updated the code. As you can see the main carschema has 2 door and 4 door and manu/auto features and I want to separate them out depending on the route variables. Could i do a post retrieval removal of data(more expensive) or get the specific schema with one route?

Comment: Oh, you're wanting to make the schema dynamic based on route params. This isn't a JSON Schema sort of thing. Sorry I can't help with that. Usually JSON Schemas are not runtime dynamic as they are provided as a contract to others as documentation. I think you're looking for more general purpose validation.

Answer (score 0):

> Can i use one schema to return custom attributes per the different options in route?

Yes, you can.

In this example, the returned data is the same, but one endpoint returns:

```
# /
{ items: [ { wheels: 4, serial: '123ASC', color: 'red' } ] }

# /no-serial
{ items: [ { wheels: 4, color: 'red' } ] }
```

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')()

fastify.get('/', {
  handler,
  schema: {
    response: {
      200: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          items: {
            type: 'array',
            items: {
              type: 'object',
              properties: {
                wheels: { type: 'number' },
                serial: { type: 'string' },
                color: { type: 'string' }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

fastify.get('/no-serial', {
  handler,
  schema: {
    response: {
      200: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          items: {
            type: 'array',
            items: {
              type: 'object',
              properties: {
                wheels: { type: 'number' },
                color: { type: 'string' }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

fastify.inject('/', (err, res) => {
  console.log(res.json())
})

fastify.inject('/no-serial', (err, res) => {
  console.log(res.json())
})

function handler (request, reply) {
  reply.send({
    items: [
      { wheels: 4, serial: '123ASC', color: 'red' }
    ]
  })
}
```

Comment: How do i distinguish the schema from my route call to it? What do i do from route perspective in calling for it?

Comment: I don't get the point, could you elaborate? Why jour handle should be aware of the schema applied?